# WPF DataGrid - update image in column using BackgroundWorkerProcess

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker

I have a datagrid with a template column. The template has an image:

```
                                                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ImageProduct" Stretch="None"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="{Binding Path=ProductImage, Mode=OneWay}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
```

The grid scrolls very slowly because the ProductImage lazilly loads a private bitmapimage object as the user scrolls the grid. I was thinking of using another thread to load the private variable (behind the ProductImage property). I'm getting into trouble with my code because of various reasons...one exception was I can only update UI on the STA thread and another was a dependency source can't be in a different thread than the dependency sink (?)

I can't think of a good way to do this. The code for the grid looks something like this with a failed attempt at the backgroundworker:

```
        var productVMList = GetProducts();

        _window.ReceivingBatchProductsGrid.ItemsSource = productVMList;

        var setProductImageWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        setProductImageWorker.DoWork += setProductImageWorker_DoWork;
        setProductImageWorker.RunWorkerAsync(productVMList);
```

And here is DoWork:

var products = (ObservableCollection)e.Argument;

```
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            product.SetProductImage();
        }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, dependency objects can only be used on the thread that created them. However, the ones that inherit from `Freezable` (like `ImageSource` for instance) *can* be used from another thread, as long as they are frozen. So when you create your `ImageSource` objects on another thread, you just need to call `Freeze` on them before you send them to the UI, and it should work fine.

An easy way to make the images load asynchronously is to use the `Binding.IsAsync` property:

```
<Image ... Source="{Binding Path=ProductImage, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}" ... />
```

That way you don't need to worry about creating a new thread and updating the target property when the image is loaded, it's handled automatically by WPF.